# Swing based Java game

Tags: java, grid-layout

this is a problem that I've been really struggling with

I need to create a game for some University coursework. The game is basically a 4x4 grid. When i click a button, the player should move randomly within 1 square of it's location.

There's enemy spaceships that are generated randomly over the grid, and if the player lands on the spaceship, it destroys it. if there's two enemy ships on the same sqaure and the player lands on that square, the player is destroyed.

I've created a GIU using `gridlayout` and the button that I need to move the player, but I'm having problems trying to figure out how to actually use the grid. I've created an `element` class to create objects for the grid (ie, a list of enemy ships), but I don't know how to use this class with my `gridlayout`. I know I also have to redraw the grid after each move to reflect the changes, but I don't know if I would need to create a custom redraw method for this.

Any push in the correct direction so I can get my program actually doing something would be really helpful.

Comment: Perhaps this article about a [2048 game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=516) in Java Swing would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I created a card game that also operated based on a `GridLayout`. Below is some of the code that was used to drive major events:

```
CardPanel extends JPanel {

public CardPanel() {
    setLayout(gridLayout);
    placeCards(N);
    chatBoxText = new JTextArea(5, 30);
}

public void placeCards(int numCards) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
        Card card = deck.distributeCard();
        String cardImageName = card.getImageName();

        JLabel jLabel = makeImage(cardImageName);
        cardSet.add(new GraphicCard(card, jLabel));

        add(jLabel);
        jLabel.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    if (GameLogic.noSetsOnBoard(cardSet)) { 
        gridLayout.setRows(gridLayout.getRows() + 1);
        placeCards(3);
    }
}

public void updateCard(Integer location) {
    Card card = deck.distributeCard();
    String cardImageName = card.getImageName();

    JLabel jLabel = makeImage(cardImageName);
    cardSet.set(location, new GraphicCard(card, jLabel));

    jLabel.addMouseListener(this);
}
}
```

The `CardPanel` here is an object that represents the `GridLayout` (you see the constructor) as well as some of those helper methods.

Further on, on particular actions, I have the following code:

```
cardPanel.removeAll();

// Some other logic here

for (GraphicCard card: cardSet) {
    cardPanel.add(card.getJLabel());
}

cardPanel.revalidate();
cardPanel.repaint();
```

In short, yes, it is custom, but it is not difficult. There are better ways to do it than the above such that you do not need to empty the entire panel in order to refresh it, the logic I have omitted above merited this particular solution.

The approach I used kept track of a `CardPanel` object which was an abstraction that contained not only the information that each box represented (in my case a card with some values), but also the graphic element to be rendered.

This was some time ago, so I don't recall the exact details but hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: I'm confused as to what your `GraphicCard` method does?

Comment: https://github.com/mmscibor/GameSet/blob/master/src/GraphicCard.java
GraphicCard is an extension (kind of) of my Card object. Some poor OOP concepts in this project, it was done fairly early in my coding career, but hopefully helps with your problem. Feel free to navigate the rest of the project